# C++ implementing vector field

Tags: c++, simulation

I'm trying to recreate a Plasma Simulation from Lubos Brieda (Plasma Simulations by Example). In doing so, I need to implement a 3D field filled with physical vectors containing the data of the electric field. (I don't want to use the  template, I'm referring to vectors in the mathematical/physical sense.)

The book shows the creation of a Field and vec3 class, to create fields of certain types and arrays (vectors) with three components.

My goal is to find the easiest way to implement a vector field, as described above. Since the book mentions that the `Field3`(`= Field_<vec3<double>>`) type has been implemented (but hasn't), I assume there is an easy option to do so without having to create a new class. I tried `using Field3 = Field_<vec3<double>>` but it always resulted in the following error:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation. **a** was nullptr.
```

[image: VectorFieldError]

Below you can see the code resulting in the error including the classes mentioned above. (I think I excluded everything non-essential. I left some comments with code lines you can use those to see that the rest of the code is working, only the `Field3` type provokes the error.)

```
#include<iostream>
#include"World.h"
#include"Field_.h"
#include"vec3.h"

int main() {
    World world(21, 21, 21);

    return 0;
}
```

```
template <typename T>
struct vec3 {
    // assign data
    vec3(const T u, const T v, const T w) : d{ u,v,w } {}
    vec3(const T a[3]) : d{ a[0],a[1],a[2] } {}
    vec3() : d{ 0,0,0 } {}

//protected:
    T d[3];
};

using double3 = vec3<double>;   // three component vector with doubles
using int3 = vec3<int>;
```

```
#pragma once
#include"vec3.h"

template<typename T>
class Field_ {  // underscore for undefined type
public:
    // constructor
    Field_(int ni, int nj, int nk) : ni{ ni }, nj{ nj }, nk{ nk }{
        data = new T * *[ni];           // ni pointers to pointers of type T
        for (int i = 0; i < ni; i++) {
            data[i] = new T * [nj];     // allocte nj pointers to T
            for (int j = 0; j < nj; j++)
                data[i][j] = new T[nk]; // allocate nk objects of type T
        }
        operator=(0);   // call the overloaded operator= function (initialize with 0)
    }

    // destructor, frees memory in reverse order
    ~Field_() {
        if (data == nullptr) return;        // return if unallocated
        for (int i = 0; i < ni; i++) {      // release memory in reverse order
            for (int j = 0; j < nj; j++)
                delete data[i][j];
            delete data[i];
        }

        delete[] data;
        data = nullptr;                     // mark as free
    }

    // overload the assignment operator
    Field_<T>& operator= (const T s) {
        std::cout << "Field_ operator=" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < ni; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nj; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < nk; k++)
                    data[i][j][k] = s;
        return *this;                           // return reference to self
    }

    const int ni, nj, nk;   // number of nodes

protected:
    T*** data;  // pointer of type T
};

using Field = Field_<double>;   // field of doubles (scalar field)
using Field3 = Field_<double3>; // field of double3s (vector field)
```

```
#pragma once
#include"vec3.h"
#include"Field_.h"

class World {
public:
    World(int ni, int nj, int nk);  //constructor

    const int ni, nj, nk;

    //Field phi;    //electric potential (scalar field)
    Field3 ef;  //electric field (vector field)
};

//World::World(int ni, int nj, int nk): ni{ ni }, nj{ nj }, nk{ nk }, phi(ni, nj, nk){}
//World::World(int ni, int nj, int nk) : ni{ ni }, nj{ nj }, nk{ nk }, phi(ni, nj, nk), ef(ni, nj, nk) {}
World::World(int ni, int nj, int nk) :
    ni{ ni }, nj{ nj }, nk{ nk }, ef(ni, nj, nk) {}
```

I hope you can help me figure out what to do and please let me know, if I can be of any assistance during that.

Comment: Since it seems you have a highly repeatable problem, it's time to deploy the debugger that came with your development environment. A debugger will usually halt when the program crashes and allow you to inspect the crash site for clues. You then use the gathered clues to see what you should inspect next. Use breakpoints to advance the program to the location of interest, and then step the program line by line looking for the unexpected, program stores the wrong value or takes the wrong path, usually. The unexpected is almost always a bug.

Comment: Closely examine `operator=(0)`. This is almost certainly the bug. `operator=` expects to be called with a `T` and it will do whatever it takes to turn that 0 into a `T`, including calling the `vec3` constructor with the 0 transformed into a null pointer.

Comment: A lot of things will become a lot easier (and will be a lot more efficient) once you replace the type `T***` of the `data` member with `std::vector<T>`, and then calculate the 3D subset index into that contiguous array. Professional dense tensor/array/field implementations are virtually always contiguous 1D arrays, not nested arrays.

Comment: Sidenote: `delete data[i][j];` should be `delete[] data[i][j];` and `delete data[i];` should be `delete[] data[i];` because you are dealing with arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far! I worked with the debugger and I believe the problem lies somewhere with `operator=` and the constructor of `vec3`.
Do you think it is possible to use the same `Field_` class for scalar values as well as my three-component-vectors? Or is there an issue, because one requires more pointers-to-pointers than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to avoid the error, because it only comes up, when trying to initialize a vector field using `operator=(0)`. But this command has to be used, if i want to initalize a scalar field with zeros. Thus using the same command for a `vec3`-type results in the error mentioned above, since the overridden `operator=` only works for scalar values. Luckily `data[i][j] = new T[nk];` already initializes `vec3`s with zeros (if `T` is some kind of `vec3` (like `double3 = vec3<double>` as I would like to use)).

My solution is to switch `operator=(0)` with:

```
if (!std::is_same<T, double3>::value) {operator=(0);}
```

So the scalar initialization is not used, when `T` is of type `double3`. In my case this should be sufficient, since all vector fields should be of type `double`. Though if I want another type, I can just adapt the if-statement.
(I think it could also be possible to check whether `T` is something like `vec3<...>`, but I haven't tried around with this jet, because I don't seem to need any other type of vector field.)